# Как найти пропущенное число в списке и вставить это число в исходный список в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Исходный список:

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Вернуть тот же список (a) с пропущенным элементом внутри

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `a = list(range(1, len(a) + 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вообще не анализировать список, а построить новый по значениям крайних элементов )

```py
a = list(range(a[0], a[-1] + 1))
```

Но если очень хочется всё же найти нужное место, то тоже нет ведь проблем:

```py
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i+1]-a[i] > 1:
        a.insert(i, a[i]+1)
        break
```